# Runtime error: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbo;

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am getting a runtime error that has to do with a firebase dependency issue. I have a feeling it is a gradle dependency issue but I haven't been able to fix my issue after setting all the google dependencies to the same version.

```
Process: com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise, PID: 21744

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method zzb(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzbo; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbo' appears in /data/app/com.clockwise.epochsoftware.clockwise-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk:classes13.dex)
     at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6331)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5923)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5862)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1718)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Here are my gradle dependencies:

```
debugCompile 'com.amitshekhar.android:debug-db:1.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'org.jdeferred:jdeferred-android-aar:1.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.0.2'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.6.0'
compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
// OneSignal SDK
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.5.3,4.0.0)'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.6.0'
```

Comment: Add some more code samples that describe the exact place where it fails in runtime

Comment: Try updating your Play Services and Firebase dependencies to 11.2.0

Comment: I updated the dependencies for google and firebase to 11.2.0 and that let me run the app. Thanks!